# std::async is not called immediately

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have some example of code. I pass `launch::async` to `async`, so I expect that lambda function will be called immediately but it won't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

mutex m;

void print(string s)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> l(m);
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main() {
    print("main thread1");

    std::future<int> f = std::async(launch::async, [](){
        print("async");
        return 1;
    });

    print("main thread2");
    int i = f.get();
    print("main thread3");

    return 0;
}
```

The result which I expect is following:

> ```
> main thread1
> async
> main thread2
> main thread3
> ```

But real output looks like that:

> ```
> main thread1
> main thread2
> async
> main thread3
> ```

Could you explain why lambda is called only when future's `get()` is called?
If I put `sleep_for` before `main thread2` output is that which I expect.

Comment: The lambda is called *asynchronously*. It may be called before, after, or simultaneously with any part of `main` between calls to `std::async` and `std::future::get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `async` returns as soon as the new thread is **created**. You now have two separate threads, and the only correlation between the operations in those two threads is that the thread created by the call to `async` must have finished before the call to `f.get()` returns. So the behavior you're seeing is consistent with the requirements. The behavior you expect is also consistent with the requirements. That's the point of running separate threads: they run independently until you do something to synchronize them.

Comment: So if I understand lambda is called as soon as possible and later return data are fetched from the second thread? So the statement "lambda is started only when `get()` is called" isn't right?

Comment: The thread function is called whenever the thread scheduler gets around to it. If the thread hasn't finished (by a call and return from the thread function) at the time when `get()` is called, the call to `get()` blocks until the thread finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation shows you do not really understand what asynchronous means. Let's take a look at the following algorithm:

```
operation1
asynchronous operation2
operation3
```

Here operation1 is being executed before the asynchronous call to operation2 is being issued. When operation2 is called asynchronously, a new thread is created and its end is not waited for. If operation3 expects operation2 to be already executed, then it is a bug in the code. If you need the result of a given thread, you will need to synchronize with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I understand what do you mean. So why when I debug the code and set breakpoint at `get()` and during executing this line lambda is started to be executed? Shouldn't `get()` only fetch data instead of starting executing lambda ?

Comment: @drewpol because the thread opened asynchronously is executed while you look at the code. We, humans are too slow for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

mutex m;

void print(string s)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> l(m);
    nanoseconds ms = duration_cast< nanoseconds >(
        system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
    );
    cout << s << "(" << ms.count() << ")" << endl;
}

int main() {
    print("main thread1");

    future<int> f = async(launch::async, [](){
        print("async");
        return 1;
    });

    //this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    print("main thread2");
    int i = f.get();
    print("main thread3");

    return 0;
}
```

Try to experiment with sleep function (`this_thread::sleep_for(2s);`) to understand what's happened.

If you want to see "async" before "main thread2" - set this sleep right before the `print` function call.

Creating threads is very hard task in every platform and OS, it takes many nanoseconds to go while just output something is much more quicker task. So, you can even add 10 more `print` calls - they will be quicker than print inside the new thread.

But `f.get()` in your code force the system to wait result. It works just like sleep. So, it's only reason why 'main thread3' is printed last in your code example.

I get output with this code:

```
./a.out 
main thread1(1534603161902827214)
main thread2(1534603161902924375)
async(1534603161902977095)
main thread3(1534603161903114658)
```

The difference is 97161 between 'main thread1' and 'main thread2'. And the difference is 190283 between 'main thread2' and 'main thread3'. All outputs are in the same thread, step by step. But this `f.get()` inhibits the last call.

Another point. C++ is very hard language and pedantic syntax is your helper against bugs in the code. You use `using namespace std;` here but write `std::` namespace anyway. It's stylistic mistake.